# Sorting a 2 dimensional array produces zeros in some values

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array, comparator

I hope some one can easily point out what bad choices I've made to get this Array sorting thing not to work.

I have a data set that I wish to sort so I can place the values in a contour(marching squares) function to draw to the screen, however I require these to be sorted in time values from smallest to largest.  Once I parse the TreeMap to a 2 dimensional array and then sort the values the SORTING process removes some values and replaces them with Zeros.

Here is the code in its entirety and also below that some results between the three Collections that I use:

**Any help is greatly appreciated… Thanks**

```
        public void paintContours(Graphics2D g2, World world, Rectangle2D bounds, Rectangle2D canvas, double scale) {

        //Class to store the three attributes for mapping.
        class Triple {  
            int t;  double x;   double y;   
            public Triple(int time, double xLoc, double yLoc) { 
                t = time;   
                x = xLoc;   
                y = yLoc;  
                }   
            }
        //Set attributes of the Renderer
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        //Do for the Pattern in the World 
        for(Pattern p: world.getPatternList().values()) {
            //Do if the pattern has at least 1 initiation point
            if(!p.getiPList().isEmpty()) {
                //Create a new Triple
                Triple store;
                //Create a new TreeMap to store all Triples
                TreeMap<Integer, Triple> map = new TreeMap<Integer, Triple>();
                //Set a counting key
                int key = 0;
                //Set the range for the rendered result
                double xmin = p.getBounds().getMinX();
                double ymin = p.getBounds().getMinY();
                double xmax = p.getBounds().getMaxX();
                double ymax = p.getBounds().getMaxY();
                //Do for all surface connectors in the pattern
                for(SurfaceConnector sc: p.getSurfaceList().values()) {
                    //Put values to map in the Triple
                    store = new Triple(sc.getTime(),sc.getTo().getEasting(),sc.getTo().getNorthing());
                    //Put the Triple in the map
                    map.put(key, store);
                    //Increment the counting key
                    key++;
                }       
                //Create a 1 dimensional array for storing time
                double [] time_1DArray = new double[map.size()];
                //Create a 2 dimentional array for storing locations
                double [] [] location_2DArray = new double[map.size()][2];
                //Create a 2 dimentional array for storing time, x, y so they can be sorted in ascending time order.
                double [] [] timeLocation_2DArray = new double[map.size()][3];
                //Do if there are values in the Treemap
                if (!(map.values().isEmpty())) {
                    //Loop through the rows
                    for (int row = 0; row < time_1DArray.length; row++) {
                        //Assign the values in the Triple TreeMap to the doubles 
                        double tt = map.get(row).t;
                        double xx = map.get(row).x;
                        double yy = map.get(row).y;
                        //Loop through the columns
                        for(int column = 0; column<3; column++) {
                            //Put the time in the first column
                            if(column == 0)         {timeLocation_2DArray[row][column] = tt;}
                            //Put the x in the second column
                            else if(column == 1)    {timeLocation_2DArray[row][column] = xx;}
                            //Put the y in the third column
                            else if(column == 2)    {timeLocation_2DArray[row][column] = yy;}
                        }

                        //Sort the array in order ascending from 0 to ∞ - based on time order
                        Arrays.sort(timeLocation_2DArray, new Comparator<double[]>() {
                            public int compare(double[] o1, double[] o2) {
                                //                                      return Double.compare(o1[0], o2[0]);
                                if (o1[0] > o2[0])      return 1;    // o1 comes after o2
                                else if (o1[0] < o2[0]) return -1;   // o1 comes before o2
                                else {                  return 0;}
                            }
                        });
                        //place sorted values in to the appropriate arrays.
                        for(int column = 0; column < 3; column++) {
                            //Time goes in the time array
                            if(column == 0) {
                                time_1DArray[row] = (timeLocation_2DArray[row][column]);
                            }
                            //X values go in the first column of the Location Array
                            else if(column == 1) {
                                location_2DArray[row][column-1] = (timeLocation_2DArray[row][column]);
                            }
                            //Y values go in the second column of the Location Array
                            else if (column == 2) {
                                location_2DArray[row][column-1] =  (timeLocation_2DArray[row][column]); 
                            }
                        }
                        //Print the Arrays for confirmation and checking - Comment out when working
                        System.out.println("Map "+ map.get(row).t +","+ map.get(row).x +","+map.get(row).y);
                        System.out.println("2D " +time_1DArray[row] +","+Arrays.toString(location_2DArray[row]));
                        System.out.println("All "+Arrays.toString(timeLocation_2DArray[row]));
                    }
                }
                //Create a new marching square algorithm
                MarchingSquares marchingSquares = new MarchingSquares();
                //Create the iso lines from the algorithm usin the above sorted arrays.
                GeneralPath[] isolines = marchingSquares.mkIsos(location_2DArray, time_1DArray); 
                //PRNTLN For checking the ascii representation of the IsoLines
                //System.out.println(marchingSquares.asciiPrintContours(array2d, array));               
                // Convert isos from array coords to world UTM coords.
//              AffineTransform xf = new AffineTransform();
                //
//              xf.scale((canvas.getWidth())/(p.getBounds().getWidth()),(canvas.getHeight())/(p.getBounds().getHeight()));

//              xf.translate(ymin, xmin);
                //          xf.translate(-1, -1); // Because MxN data was padded to (M+2)x(N+2).
                for (int i = 0; i < isolines.length; i++) {

//                  isolines[i].transform(xf); // Permanent mapping to world coords.

                    Shape iso = (isolines[i]); // Remapped every pan & zoom.
                    g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                    g2.setStroke(LINE_250);

                    g2.draw(iso); // Color iso.
                    g2.setStroke(DASH_200_008);
                    g2.setColor(Color.YELLOW);

                    g2.draw(iso); // Outline iso.
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

**OUTPUT**
Map 609,1097.1538,5107.53
2D 0.0,[0.0, 0.0]
All [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
Map 676,1094.6538,5112.53
2D 0.0,[0.0, 0.0]
All [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
Map 592,1092.1538,5107.53
2D 0.0,[0.0, 0.0]
All [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
Map 752,1124.6538,5102.53
2D 1154.0,[1067.1538, 5127.53]
All [1154.0, 1067.1538, 5127.53]
Map 861,1127.1538,5107.53
2D 1154.0,[1067.1538, 5127.53]
All [1154.0, 1067.1538, 5127.53]
Map 1037,1127.1538,5117.53
2D 1154.0,[1067.1538, 5127.53]
All [1154.0, 1067.1538, 5127.53]
Map 1213,1127.1538,5127.53
2D 1213.0,[1127.1538, 5127.53]
All [1213.0, 1127.1538, 5127.53]

[image: Picture of Data Set with dysfunctional contour in top right corner (Yellow and Black)]

Comment: Either fully initialize `timeLocation_2DArray` before sorting it with `Arrays.sort` or use `Arrays.sort(..., 0, row+1, new Co...)` to restrict sorting to the initialized part of the array. Otherwise your data (with positive time) will be sorted to the end of the array. Your array contains all zeroes after allocating it with `new double[...][3]`.)

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response.  The sort is now working.  I took the sort and the "sorted placement into arrays" outside of the first loop and created another and it now has fixed the sort issue. Cheers Halfbit.